# Retrieving values from Model C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `C# MVC Model` as follows;

```
public class MyModel
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<MyModel> allDetails { get; set; }
    public int age { set; get; }
    public string gender { set; get; }
    public int schoolid { set; get; }
    ...
}
```

Now want to retrieve data from `allDetails`. How can i do it ?

In the `controller`;

```
model.allDetails = MyDetails.getAllDetails(); // Saves all details in the Model
```

Now how can i retrieve `age, gender and school` from this `model`; My approach as follows (but its doesn't work)

```
model.allDetails.age; // This doesn't work
```

Comment: What is the code on your view? Are you sure you are passing data into the `allDetails` from your view?

Comment: The output is not going to be used in the view. I am using the values of the module to further process inside the controller it self.

Answer (score 2):

In your code model.allDetails is a list (or smth else that implements IEnumerable), so you have to use foreach or another loop, or just First() to get first value from it: model.allDetails.First().age

Answer (score 0):

I think you got your desing for class `MyModel` wrong, You should probably have two classes like:

```
public class MyClass
{
        ...
        public IEnumerable<MyModel> allDetails { get; set; }
        public int age { set; get; }
        public string gender { set; get; }
        public int schoolid { set; get; }
        ...
}


public class MyModel
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> allDetails { get; set; }
    ...

}
```

Where your `MyModel` class will contain an `IEnumerable` of your other class which contains properties. Later you can fill your model through controller.

In your current `MyModel` class, you are keeping IEnumerable of the class itself, so each object for that class will have another IEnumerable and so on.

You may also see: [C# Coding Conventions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx) for your properties names.